# How would I over-ride Backbone.Sync while using RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, amd

I am trying to use [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) along with [backbone.iobind](https://github.com/logicalparadox/backbone.iobind) (a replacement for the default `Backbone.Sync` method to communicate using socket.io).

I am also now trying to use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).  I've tried a few different ways to get everything working including:

- [Removing the prefix from the backbone.iobind and backbone.iosync files and wrapping them in a requirejs](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/backboneiobind/2VNvQNU_Apg) `define(['backbone' ... ], function(Backbone ...) { ... });`
- Trying to shim backbone/underscore
- Trying the AMD enabled fork of backbone/[underscore](https://github.com/amdjs/backbone/)

Thank you.